# How to handle Incompatibility of Firefox and Gpj , JCmanager and GPshell?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader

I have an ACR38 smart card reader.When the Firefox is Open in my computer, I can't use my smart card reader via gpshell , Gpj and jcmanager!! and when I close Firefox and kill it's process in "Windows Task Manager" everything will be solved!
The question is, How I can have both of these softwares open simultaneously?
Thank you.

Note : the error message that I receive of the gpshell / gpj and jcmanager is something like "The reader is in use by another application!!" I'll be post a picture of error tomorrow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've installed a PKCS#11 module in Firefox that requests exclusive access to the reader. Either remove the PKCS#11 (also known as cryptoki) dll or configure it is such a way that it does not use exclusive access (in the PCSC layer).

Comment: thank you dear owlstead.but I don't know how to configure it such a way that it does not use exclusive access! can you help me plz to do it?

Comment: no, because that depends on the P11, it may not be possible.